# Error calling elmah.axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I'm trying to setup elmah on my web app,I changed web.config,executed Sql script on my db,added reference to elmah.dll and everything compiles fine but while debugging when I try to access http://localhost:someport/elmah.axd I get following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Call stack loaction:

```
Elmah.DLL!Elmah.SimpleServiceProviderFactory.CreateFromConfigSection(string sectionName)
```

Source File Information:

```
Locating source for 'c:\builds\ELMAH\src\Elmah\SimpleServiceProviderFactory.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {f6 f8 c9 b cf 41 f7 11 7d de 16 2b ed 30 e4 83}
The file 'c:\builds\ELMAH\src\Elmah\SimpleServiceProviderFactory.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\builds\ELMAH\src\Elmah\SimpleServiceProviderFactory.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\builds\ELMAH\src\Elmah\SimpleServiceProviderFactory.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\builds\ELMAH\src\Elmah\SimpleServiceProviderFactory.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\builds\ELMAH\src\Elmah\SimpleServiceProviderFactory.cs'.
```

What is this SimpleServiceProviderFactory.cs class I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using the NuGet package?  For me the package version just worked.

Comment: I will try and get back here if it worked.

Comment: One other comment, after using NuGet package, if you are building an MVC app, you might have to add an ignore route for elmah `routes.IgnoreRoute("admin/elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}");`

Comment: @dtryon I'm not building MVC. It's Web Forms, and the NuGet version worked liked charm, thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet installation worked correctly, and it's much much easier then doing it manually!